Как спарсить данные с сайта в виде одного цельногоизображения?
Условно, есть сайт, мне нужно не конкретное изображение или текст, а всё содержимое заголовка div в виде картинки. Пожалуйста, подскажите как это можно реализовать
ссылка на страницу картинки с примера: https://tayniymir.com/goroskop/today/strelets/man
Класс, который отвечает за часть, которая должна быть сохранена в картинке 'full_desc_goroskop_head'


from playwright.sync_api import sync_playwright

with sync_playwright() as playwright:
    browser = playwright.chromium.launch()
    page = browser.new_page()
    page.goto("https://tayniymir.com/goroskop/today/strelets/man")
    element = page.query_selector('.full_desc_goroskop_head')
    element.screenshot(path='screenshot.png')


Решила вопрос с помощью selenium и обрезки изображения после получения страницы:
import time
from selenium import webdriver
from PIL import Image

DRIVER = 'chromedriver'
driver = webdriver.Chrome(DRIVER)
driver.get('https://tayniymir.com/goroskop/today/kozerog/man')
screenshot = driver.save_screenshot('my_screenshot.png')
time.sleep(1)
driver.close()
img = Image.open('my_screenshot.png')
img_crop = img.crop((63, 581, 859,844)).save('my_screenshot.png')

